# GNU Screen: weird keyboard movements in zsh

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen

If I type `End` in non-screen environment of my `zsh` console - it will move me to the end of line.
But if I do the same in `zsh` behind screen then it will just upper case following word..

How can I make those movements behave the same in `screen` environment too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `~/.screenrc` file add one of the following lines:

```
bindkey "\eOF" end-of-line
bindkey "\e[8~" end-of-line
bindkey "\eOw" end-of-line
```

depending on what you get when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> at a shell prompt. Escape is represented by `^[`.

Alternatively, you can try setting `TERM` while you're in `screen` to the same thing it is outside `screen`.

Comment: Ctrl-v End gives me "[4~" what should I do then? it is not listed in these three lines and 'bindkey "\e[4~" end-of-line' doesn't help.. any  ideas, Dennis? P.S. TERM is the same now

Comment: @user80805: Did you get "[4~" or "^[[4~"? Was that with or without `screen` running? Do you have any keys mapped using zsh's `bindkey`?

Comment: I get "^[[4~". It was with `screen`. No custom bindkeys - just that http://pastie.org/1219134

Comment: @user80805: Nothing keyboard-related in `~/.zshrc`?